# What is the optimal way to ensure a max absolute value, but preserve the sign?

Tags: math, absolute

Say we have code like;

```
if (x > 6) {
    x = 6;
}
if (x < -6) {
    x = -6;
}
```

Can we reduce this to one check and one update?

We could do this, but we lose the sign.

```
if (abs(x) > 6) {
    x = 6;
}
```

(i'm not assuming any particular language)

Comment: `x = min(max(x, -6), 6)`

Comment: I guess I need to multiply by the sign of the original number, and finding the sign is probably easy or difficult depending upon the language.

Comment: To be honest, I think your original code is still the easiest to read and understand. I personally would wrap into a function `limit(x, lowerBound, upperBound)` that returns x if it's between lowerBound and upperBound or otherwise one of the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sign` function, you could use

```
x = sign(x) * min(6, abs(x))
```

Or, if you prefer the `copysign` function [where copysign(x, y) returns a float with the magnitude (absolute value) of x but the sign of y],

```
x = copysign(min(6, abs(x)), x)
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was look for, 1 simple line of code. However thinking about it, it's probably less optimal because it involves 3 function calls. So I probably should have phrased the question differently.